# Has the Heroku SSL certificate expired?

Tags: git, ssl, heroku

When trying to deploy my code to Heroku (`git push -u heroku master`), I get the following error:

```
SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

Does anyone else experience a similar issue?

Comment: always post the entire log. You make the question seem the fault with Heroku's SSL. But it could also be your project attempting to install dependencies from third parties whose SSL are expired. Posting the full log provides better insight what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s apparently expired. Working now again.